# Giving an upper bound for the recurrance T(n) = T(floor(n/2)) + n

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

I am able to get O(nlogn) correctly. But I also thought O(n) would work, except [here](https://www.d.umn.edu/~ddunham/cs4521f09/notes/ch04.txt) it mentions that O(n) is wrong because "The error is that we haven't proved the exact form of the inductive hypothesis: T(n) <= cn." I'm not sure what that means.

This is what I do:

```
T(n) <= cn
T(n) <= 2c*floor(n/2) + n
T(n) <= 2c*n/2 + n
cn   <= n(c + 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"The error is that we haven't proved the exact form of the inductive hypothesis: T(n) <= cn."* means the following:

You start with a guess:

```
T(n) <= cn
```

and you end up with this:

```
T(n) <= cn + n
```

But that is not something you can prove your guess with. In other words, this implication is not true:

```
T(n) <= cn + n ⟹ T(n) <= cn
```

Yet, that is what you are after to make the proof sound. You could say, well I will just start of with this guess then:

```
T(n) <= (c+1)n
```

But you will always get to larger expressions, which do not imply your guess.